# Degraded video performance after wake from sleep (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I recently upgraded my system with an SSD for my boot drive, so I had to format and reinstall Windows 7.  I have always put my desktop into sleep mode when I'm not using it, and has worked without any issues.  Since my SSD upgrade, I have had horribly degraded video performance after waking my system from sleep.

I'll play **any** game, and my framerates drop to a *quarter* of what they usually are, but *only after sleep.*

My hardware specs as follows:

- ASUS Sabertooth X58
- Intel Core i7 950 @ Stock 3GHz
- 6GB DDR3 Memory: 3 x G.Skill F3-12800CL7-2GBPI
- EVGA GeForce GTX 470 SC x 2 in SLI
- ASUS Xonar DX PCIe 1x
- Crucial M4 128GB SSD, SATA3

Video driver: NVIDIA WHQL 302.42, official.

**I have tried the following:**

1. Disable Hybrid Sleep mode in Power Options
2. Enabled S3 video resume in BIOS setup

Could it be chipset drivers, video drivers, or BIOS firmware related to S3?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This is a bit late as a comment, but for future visitors: Check the log file for error messages. There might just be a 'Warning: Failed to resume videodriver.dll' equivalents in the eventviewer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace the RAM that you are using such as from Kingston or Crucial? Or, Can you enable ESS and see if it help?

Typically, when you put PC in a sleep or hibernation mode, it saves information on hibernate.sys file (which is a image of the RAM setting with all the null pointers and fragmentation of memory). So when you wakeup the PC some of the memory "could' have become corrupted by saving on SSD.

Finally, why not simply shut the PC since it should not take more than 5 minutes to operate.